# Retrieve a list of entities from a Restfull service (inside client app)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, client, entities

Im new to Rest web services and say Ive created this web service using Netbeans

```
@Path("browse")
@Stateless
public class ArticleBrowseResource {

   @EJB
   private ArticleSearcherLocal ejbRef;

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public List<Article> browse(@DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("username") String username,@QueryParam("sd") String sd) {

      // convert sd string to date
      List<Article> articles = ejbRef.search(username, date);
      return articles;
   }
}
```

where `Article` is an entity which is anotated with `@XmlRootElement`

Now how am I supossed to retreive this list of articles in my **client** which for simplicity lets just say it is a java standard application? In SOAP web services I know that these objects are automatically generated but not in Rest.

This is the client class generated for this service by Netbeans

```
public class ArticleBrowseClient {
  private WebResource webResource;
  private Client client;
  private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/cityblog/rest";

  public ArticleBrowseClient() {
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
    client = Client.create(config);
    webResource = client.resource(BASE_URI).path("browse");
  }

  public <T> T browse(Class<T> responseType, String username, String sd) throws UniformInterfaceException {
    WebResource resource = webResource;
    if (username != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("username", username);
    }
    if (sd != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("sd", sd);
    }
    return resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
  }

  public void close() {
    client.destroy();
  }

}
```

What is the best and simplest way to resolve this issue?

Any help is appreciated and 
thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try fewer code generation and more understanding of what you are actually doing. On the server, you generate a XML message with help of JAXB. On the client side, you can consume this XML with a programming language and library you like. Just use tools like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to see what is going actually over "the wire". Your generated client site looks fully reasonable. You just need your Article class from the server side on the client side. The generated code uses [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) which can read XML messages per JAXB per default. So just drop your server side Article class in your client side classpath and use it. But please also have a look at the wire level protocol to understand the portability of your REST API.

Comment: hari was right. If you use SOAP Webservices in netbeans, it generates automatically all classes in the client with the help of wsimport. So the question was, is there an opportunity to generate the classes automatically for RESTful Service (and not to set them manually into the classpath).